# NameError: uninitialized constant Mail::TestMailer on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm getting this error

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Mail::TestMailer
```

on my Ruby on Rails project on Elastic Beanstalk.

Other sources told me to install 3 gems.

```
gem 'net-smtp', '>= 0.3.3'
gem 'net-imap', '>= 0.1.2'
gem 'net-pop', '>= 0.1.2'
```

I have already installed them, but it still does not work.
`eb deploy` fails every time.

> Ruby version 3.0.5, rails 6.1.7

Code from application mailer, not sure if this helps but just in case.

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'from@example.com'
  layout 'mailer'
end
```

Please see the error log below
`eb deploy Creating application version archive "app-4523-230109_233425301397". Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done... 2023-01-09 14:38:30    INFO    Environment update is starting.       2023-01-09 14:38:36    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s). 2023-01-09 14:40:51    ERROR   Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'. 2023-01-09 14:40:53    ERROR   [Instance: i-0e263523f982bac43] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error.. 2023-01-09 14:40:53    INFO    Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1]. 2023-01-09 14:40:53    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0e263523f982bac43'. Aborting the operation. 2023-01-09 14:40:54    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.`        
I hope this helps.
Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: The phrase *it still does not work* is not diagnostically useful information. The best answer that anyone can give you is *if you say so*.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the entire error message (including the stack trace). Also show the exact command you are running, as well as parts of code you have adapted which might affect this (i.e. likely code you have written which is mentioned near the top of the stack trace)